# Comma separated checkbox value is not get selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a checkbox with single word value like

```
<div id="search">
 <input type="checkbox" value="Houston" >
</div>
```

Than I can make it selected using below JQuery

```
$('#search').find("input:checkbox[value=Houston]")
            .attr("checked", true);
```

But, If my value is comma separated like `value="Texas, Houston"` than I can't make checkbox selected but got a error like:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:checkbox[value=Houston, Texas]
```

How I can solve this error?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), the attribute value in your selector can be *"either an unquoted single word or a quoted string"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `,` is a meta character, You need to pass `Texas, Houston` with in quotes like `value='Texas, Houston'`

*Use*

```
$('#search').find("input:checkbox[value='Texas, Houston']")
        .prop("checked", true);
```

Also if you are using jQuery 1.6+, you should use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

**Other ways**

Read [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

You can also use

```
$('#search').find("input:checkbox[value=Houston\\,Texas]")
```